# How to create a tuple from dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, namedtuple

```py
from collections import namedtuple    
BookPlan = namedtuple('Book', ['size', 'weight'])
books = BookPlan(3, 5), BookPlan(4, 9)
i=0
book={}
while (i<3):
    book['size'] = i
    book['weight'] = i*5
    i=i+1
    books=books+BookPlan(**book)
print (books)
```

I would like to get something like this:

```py
Book(size=3, weight=5), Book(size=4, weight=9), Book(size=1, weight=5), Book(size=2, weight=10)
```

But in fact I get:

```
(Book(size=3, weight=5), Book(size=4, weight=9), 1, 5, 2, 10)
```

It turned out something like concatenation of the `namedtuple` and `tuple`. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `books = books + (BookPlan(**book),)`

Answer (score 1):

books = books + (BookPlan(**book),)

thanks to falsetru